# facebook like button dont work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

i use a xfbml facebook like button in this website:
http://www.pediasure.co.il.

When you click the like button on the home page it's look like everything is ok.
but the like not publishing on the wall.

and in this link:
http://www.pediasure.co.il/heb/%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D/#tab12

if you click on one of the images it will slide down and you will see a like button now when you click on it it's show an red error

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is: just not to use Unicode chars in the url. and  urlEncode not helping to...
it's work only for url that contain only ascii chars!

and avoiding the '%XX' in the url.